# Using multiple decorators with Pyinvoke @task decorator

Tags: python-2.7, pyinvoke

I am attempting to create a decorator, and use it alongside the [pyinvoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) `@task` decorator.

See:

```
def extract_config(func):
    print func

    def func_wrapper(cfg=None):
        config = read_invoke_config(cfg)
        return func(**config)

    return func_wrapper


@extract_config
@task
def zip_files(config):
    import zipfile
    ...
```

However, now from the command line when I execute

`inv zip_files`

I receive the output:

`<Task 'zip_files'>
No idea what 'zip_files' is!`

No matter if `@task` comes before or after `@extract_config`, I lose
the invoke task functionality and it doesn't recognize the function name..

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's a bug raised for the issue: https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/555, still open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax:

```
@deco1
@deco2
def func(): pass
```

Is pretty much equivalent to:

```
def func(): pass
func = deco1(deco2(func))
```

So the decorator on the first line is applied after the decorator on the second line.

The `task` decorator you are using from your library returns a `Task` object rather than another function, so your outer decorator may not be doing the right thing when replacing it in the global namespace with a wrapper function. To make it work, you'd need your `wrapper` to be an object that mimics all the relevant behavior of the `Task` object (I have no idea how easy or difficult that might be).

A more straight forward approach may be to reverse the order of the decorators:

```
@task
@extract_config
def zip_files(config):
```

This is probably closer to working, but I suspect it still goes wrong for a simple reason. Your `extract_config` decorator returns a function with a different name than `zip_files` (it returns the function named `wrapper`, which hasn't made any effort to change its `__name__` attribute), so the `Task` object doesn't know its name properly.

To fix this, I'd suggest using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in the decorator to copy the relevant attributes of the wrapped function into the wrapper function:

```
def extract_config(func):
    print func

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(cfg=None):
        config = read_invoke_config(cfg)
        return func(**config)

    return func_wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get Blcknght's solution to work, but I found a workaround:

```py
def decorator(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def _decorated(ctx, *args, **kwargs):
        return fn(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
    return _decorated

@invoke.task
def some_task(ctx, config="Something"):
    @decorator
    def _inner(ctx):
        print(config)
        ...

    return _inner(ctx)
```

Wrapping the inner function prevents it from obscuring the underlying function, allowing invoke to recognise the decorator and allow it to inspect the arguments of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! In this example, only adding the [`@functools.wraps(fn)`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) decorator did the trick to my own decorator!